# How to keep track of how much profile a user has completed in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

I have a Spring Boot project in which a user can create his/her profile, which may not be completed in one sitting.

I want to keep track of how much profile is completed, probably in percentage, and show it to the user.

I was thinking of checking all the fields for null but that seems tedious as there are already about 25 fields, which might increase in future.

While researching about this, I found some answers on SO about using java reflection, but I also came to know that **refleciton is slow, and it creates fragile code.**
(I am using java 11)

Other than checking nulls in the fields of each user, is there a better way to keep track of profile completeness?

Answer (score 1):

You have `n` fields. Assuming that 0 <= `k` <= `n` fields were already filled, you have **(100 * k / n*)%* completed. Now, you only need to:

- initialize `k` with 0 upon form completion start
- increment `k` whenever a field is filled
- decrement `k` whenever a filled field gets unfilled
- display the new percentages whenever `k` changes
- if a new field is created for the forms, increment `n`
- if a field no longer exists, decrement `n`
- you need to decide whether you count all your fields into the completion percentage or only the required fields
- upon page reload, you might want to preserve the form values. You can use `localStorage` to store the current status whenever a field changes, storing all the filled values
- upon page reload the number of filled values stored into `localStorage` will be the value of `k`